# How to extract simple wpf markup to usercontrol with databinding of VM

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I feel dumb for having to ask this but I've been reading both Microsoft and non-Micorosoft documentation all weekend and it all is either far to simplistic, or covering some strangely esoteric cases that are not relevant to me.

What I need is very simple. I have some markup

```
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Margin="55,3,15,0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="303*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="156*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextSettings.PlayerNumber}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PlayerNumber}" />
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
```

For a variety of reasons I want the contents of that viewbox to live in another file. It doesn't even have to be re-usable, It just has to be in a UserControl that I can either include, or not include, or include a different one based on application state.

What I can't figure out is how to move that `Grid` into is own UserControl and have the bindings continue working. I assume that I would have to pass the ViewModel from the parent view into the child via a parameter, but for the life of me I cannot find an example of the correct syntax.

So. If that was to be moved to its own UserControl,

1. What would the UserControl look like?
2. What would I need to add to the UserControl's codebehind ot get the binding working?
3. What would the inclusion point look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data context will be inherited down the visual tree. So just define your `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="303*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="156*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextSettings.PlayerNumber}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PlayerNumber}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then in your parent window you will need to declare the namespace of the user control:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Then use it:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Margin="55,3,15,0">
    <local:MyUserControl/>
</Viewbox>
```